# Calling a function of en external javascript file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, path, call

In general... How can I make a call on a function of an external java script file?

More specific...

- In the head tag i have

`<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript/FontSize.js"></script>`

- The external javascript file, (that i would like to call) `FontSize.js` contains the following functions.

  ```
  function checkCookie()

  function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays)

  function getCookie(c_name)

  function increaseFontSize()

  function decreaseFontSize()`
  ```
- The FontSize.js is located at the `~/Jscript/` directory

I guess the body on load should contain something like

`<body onload="/JScript/Fontsize.js/checkCookie()">`

Of course nothing works as it should because, i do not know how to make the call to a function to an external js file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just call it as if it were local :)

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

Or, do it in script:

```
window.onload = checkCookie;
```

When you declare a function and it's not in another object/namespace, it's just globally available, and you can call it as if it immediately preceded your current code.  By default these functions will be on the `window` object, [you can see a short demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzSq3/).

For example (doesn't matter *where* this function's defined, external or not):

```
function myFunc() { alert('hi'); }
myFunc();
window.myFunc(); //same call, unless there's *another* myFunc in a local-er scope
```

Comment: @strakastroukas - Are you sure the relative path to your external file is correct, e.g. View -> Page source, click on it's link, does it come up correctly?  For your current code, your page would have to be at the `~/Page.htm` level.

Comment: That was it! I edited that to <script type="text/javascript" src="../JScript/FontSize.js"></script> (Added the ../ to the path)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

    <!--The extranal main.js file contains samp() function.. -->
            <script>
              <!--    samp(); -->
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```